# Is it possible to show the 'back side' of the earth with matplotlib basemap using orthographic projection?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Basically I want to make the body of the Earth "transparent" so that an object (a point or a patch, etc) and its antipodal image can be displayed simultaneously on the same orthographic map.  Is this possible to do with matplotlib and basemap?

Answer (score 2):

How about just plotting two projections? It's a bit of a cheat, but here you go:

```
import pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

front_central_lon = 70
m1 = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=0, lon_0=front_central_lon)
m2 = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=0, lon_0=front_central_lon + 180)

# m2.drawcoastlines(color='gray')
# m1.drawcoastlines()

m2.fillcontinents(color='coral', alpha=0.3)
m1.fillcontinents(color='coral', alpha=0.8)
m1.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,91.,30.))
m1.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,60.))


plt.show()
```

[image: Front and back orthographic]

Comment: This is wrong: America is flipped in the east-west direction! (Brasil is on the Pacific and Chile is on the Atlantic)